# PDFBox "This font does not permit subsetting" - Possible to use font without subsetting?

Tags: java, fonts, pdfbox

I used PDFBox (2.0.11) to create/edit PDFs and struggled with the usage of two fonts that always lead to an exception as follows

```
This font does not permit subsetting
```

Even though it is possible to subset the fonts with other tools like [Everything fonts](https://everythingfonts.com/subsetter) without any issues.

Is it possible to use a font with PDFbox without subsetting it or are there any other ways to solve this problem?

**Exception message:**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: This font does not permit subsetting
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.TrueTypeEmbedder.subset(TrueTypeEmbedder.java:298)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDType0Font.subset(PDType0Font.java:239)
```

**SOLVED:**

Here is a working example on how to load a font without subsetting it:

```
File fontFile1 = new File("/fonts/fontfile.ttf");
InputStream fontFile1Stream = new FileInputStream(fontFile1);
PDType0Font product_title_font = PDType0Font.load(doc, fontFile1Stream, false);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can still use the font without subsetting, use

```
PDType0Font.load(PDDocument doc, InputStream input, boolean embedSubset)
```

with the last parameter = false. Your files will be bigger, that's all. If another product can subset the font, then it means either that it doesn't respect the license settings, or that there's a bug in PDFBox. Open your font in a tool that can display the os2 table, e.g. DTL OTMaster Light. There look for the "fstype" entry.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/opentype/spec/os2#fstype